# How to set an uninstalled package as installed in pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I want to set two packages that I (stupidly) installed without using pacman as installed, so I don't have to bother uninstalling them and reinstalling through pacman.

Comment: It's impossible to know *how* you've installed these packages if not through pacman. But that's important. But just letting you know that the answers will likely boil down to: "you might have installed something similar, but not the same as pacman installing the package would have. The fastest, and only safe way out is installing it through pacman, so do that, it should take seconds."